# Washed-out colors with canvas createConicGradient() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas, gradient, conic-gradients

I'm experiencing an issue with the `ctx.createConicGradient()` method in Firefox where the colors appear to be desaturated and washed out. This issue seems to be specific to Firefox as the same code works fine in Chrome, and other gradient methods like `ctx.createLinearGradient()` and `ctx.createRadialGradient()` also work correctly in both browsers.

This is how example conic gradient from [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createConicGradient) looks like for me in Firefox:

[image]

Same example in Chrome:

[image]

I have observed this issue in both Firefox Developer Edition and Firefox Nightly. Adjusting Firefox's color management settings (`gfx.color_management.mode` and `gfx.color_management.enablev4`) and restarting the browser did not resolve the issue.

Interestingly, applying the same gradient multiple times intensifies the colors but only up to a point, suggesting that the issue might be related to how Firefox handles alpha or opacity in conic gradients.

Can anyone confirm if they're experiencing the same issue, or suggest any potential solutions? I'm interested in getting native createConicGradient() method to work and would like to avoid polyfills and hacks.

Comment: Open an issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi#h=dupes%7CFirefox No repro for me on macOS's 120.0a1. Things to check, is it really opacity: change the background of the canvas element in that example and see if it affects the result. See if hardware acceleration is activated (Graphics section in `about:support`). Try to disable it if it is (`about:config`> `gfx.canvas.accelerated`). Check if the resolution of your monitor has something to do with it (try another zoom level, another monitor, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much for that report - I started to get crazy about that. Same issue here.